# UPDATE: How to fix SQL error in procedure statement : NEW ERROR

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, sqlplus, auto-populate

Im creating sql database and i have many different tables connectdd with different entity relationships.

Im currently working on 1:N relationship and im population data to tables using procedures.

I've made a little progress but i keep stumbling on tiny erros and i have problems fixing them.

I just got into one which i just cannot fix. I've been looking at a cold for like an hour now and im guess it might be right there but i just can't see it.

Anyway...

**This is the code**

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE CENIK (
ID_CENIK INTEGER NOT NULL,
CENA NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
DATUM_OD DATE NOT NULL,
DATUM_DO DATE NOT NULL,
TK_ID_ARTIKEL NUMBER(10) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE CENIK
ADD (CONSTRAINT PK_CENIK PRIMARY KEY (ID_CENIK));

ALTER TABLE CENIK
ADD (CONSTRAINT TK_CENIK_ID_ARTIKEL FOREIGN KEY
(TK_ID_ARTIKEL) REFERENCES ARTIKEL(ID_ARTIKEL));
```

**Procedure code**

```
--polnjenje tabele cenik
PROCEDURE polni_cenik(stevilo_cenikov NUMBER) IS
cena_artikla NUMBER(10);
datum_od DATE;
datum_do DATE;
c_tk_id_artikel NUMBER(10);
c_stevilo_artiklov int;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(ID_ARTIKEL) INTO c_stevilo_artiklov FROM ARTIKEL;
    FOR st14 IN 1..stevilo_cenikov LOOP
        cena_artikla := dbms_random.value(1,9999);
        datum_od := SYSDATE();
        datum_do := SYSDATE();
        datum_od := datum_od - dbms_random.value(0,1000);
        datum_do := datum_do + dbms_random.value(0,1000);
        c_tk_id_artikel := round(dbms_random.value(1,c_stevilo_artiklov));
        INSERT INTO CENIK(ID_CENIK, DATUM_OD, DATUM_DO, TK_ID_ARTIKEL)
        VALUES (st14, datum_od, datum_do, c_tk_id_artikel);
        dbms_output.put_line (st14);
    END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
```

**And this is the error**

[image]

Comment: @toddlermenot im sorry i did that, i promise ill use this thread for another issues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ime_kraja := ||' '|| TO_CHAR(st);` should be `ime_kraja := TO_CHAR(st);` or you forgot something before the first `||`.

Comment: . . I suspect it should be `ime_kraja := ime_kraja || ' ' || TO_CHAR(st)`

Comment: thank you very much. been working whole day and my eyes are just 2 tired. thank you again!

Comment: @GordonLinoff, the power of induction eh? :)

Comment: @fox . . . You should take a moment to accept this answer, if you found it useful.